# Javascript on visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Hi im using visual studio 2017 and i have an html based site.
I want use slick slider that already working on codepen but when i put in visual studio the javascript doesnt work please help me!

[Slider Example](https://codepen.io/ChristosX/pen/yvBvJE)

```
console.clear();
  $(".slider").slick({
      autoplay: true,    
      slidesToShow: 4,
      dots: false,
      responsive: [{ 
          breakpoint: 500,
          settings: {
              dots: false,
              arrows: false,
              infinite: false,
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 2
          } 
      }]
  });
```

Comment: I think we're going to need you to be a bit more specific than "doesn't work". Surely you get console errors of some kind?

Comment: Probably, you should import some external JS to make the slider work? jQuery and the Slick slider are not contained in your browser

Comment: Perran I mean that i have this result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ0yR.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if you added the library at the head tag in your code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Also, be sure you load it before your script. In codepen you can add the library in the settings, so maybe you forgot to load it in your code in VS. If that doesn't solve your problem, it would be nice if you take a look at your console error... So we can know the problem and help you better.

Comment: I don't get any error, the site running normally but the result isn't same as i expect, with other words if I have the. Js file or if I don't its the same :D

Comment: insert alert("test") inside your jQuery call, to see if its working, and try to debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

My libraries is:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://anijs.github.io/lib/anicollection/anicollection.css"/> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
   <script src="js/test.js"></script>
```

As you can see in first photo i have already put into a test.js that include all javascrpit code tha im calling into my aspx

My css file:

```
#dealss .slick-slider {
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 1;
text-align: center;
color: white;
```

}

```
.slick-slide {
background: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
padding: 40px 0;
```

}

And my result is : 
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ0yR.jpg)